# Se me presenta un problema al eliminar un registro en java en un jtable

Tags: java

Al seleccionar un reg en una columna con un checkbox se me marca toda la fila de azul y al marcar la fila de azul no se logra eliminar pues no me reconoce el valor booleano del checkbox y como no lo reconoce no lo logro eliminar este es la imagen [image: Como ven se marca azul toda la fila]

este es el codigo del eliminar `public void leeRifIdentif(){
         String RIF;
         int cont=0;
         TableModel model = datalistado.getModel();
            for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){ 
                if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 0) == true){
                    RIF=((String)model.getValueAt(i, 1));
                    cont++;
                        try{
                             ps =cn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rif=?");
                             String rif = String.valueOf(RIF);
                             ps.setString(1,rif);
                             ps.executeUpdate();
                             MostrarDatos(false);
                             VaciarCampos();

                        }catch(Exception e){
                             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
               }

            }
            if(cont == model.getRowCount()){
                 CboCampo.setSelected(false);
           }
   }`

 al momento de evaluar la condición para saber si es true como esta marcada la fila me la toma false

Comment: Si lo comparas como String nada mas? No has probado? if(model.getValueAt(i, 0).equals("true"))

Comment: que te trae como valor (Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 0)??

Comment: @Angel  la condición (Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 0) == true es la que falla cuando la fila esta en azul como en la foto

Comment: @josego la condición (Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 0) == true es la que falla cuando la fila esta en azul como en la foto

Comment: Pero quiero saber que valor esta trayendo. Hace un system.out.println para ver su valor

Comment: @josego me trae false

Comment: @Angel esa condición no me sirvió

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo todo el código completo para ayudarte. Pero este deberías de borrar solamente lo seleccionado.

En el código que presentas esta dentro de un for. 
Algo así te va a servir. Agrega dentro de tu método leeRifIdentif

```
....
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.table.getModel();
   int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
   for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
     // Aca borras de tu model.
     model.removeRow(rows[i]-i);

     // Borras de tu base de datos.
   }
}
```

Como no tengo todo el código no se desde donde estas llamando tu leeRifIdentif. Asumo que desde un evento al seleccionar tus registros

Comment: pero ya va ese código iría donde? @josego

Comment: podes usar un método aparte,, pero agregale nomas dentro de tu método leeRifIdentif.

Comment: y en que parte verifico si se selecciono la fila? @josego

Comment: no hace falta que verifiques. donde dice int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows(); te va a salir las lineas que seleccionaste

Comment: gracias mano me sirvió @josego

Comment: @Efrainrodc por nada. Estamos para ayudarnos.

Comment: disculpa otra vez pero el int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows(); solo me devuelve uno seleccionado y eso que seleccione varios

Comment: tenes que agregarle lo siguiente a tu table. table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

Comment: así lo tengo: DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)this.datalistado.getModel();
            datalistado.setRowSelectionAllowed(true); 
            datalistado.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_‌​SELECTION);
            int[] rows = datalistado.getSelectedRows();   
            
            for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){

Comment: asi lo tengo :así lo tengo: DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)this.datalistado.getModel();
            datalistado.setRowSelectionAllowed(true); 
            datalistado.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_‌​SELECTION);
            int[] rows = datalistado.getSelectedRows();   
            
            for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){

Comment: No deberías de agregar cuando configuras tu table. Si seguís con problemas. Abrí una nueva pregunta porque esto ya es otra cosa. Gracias

Comment: el único problema es que me agarra solo una fila y me has dicho que tenia que agregarle eso pero en que parte antes o después del int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();?

Comment: al crear tu table

Comment: lo he intentado pero nada @josego